# Label text not updating on a form instantiated from a DLL

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, visual-studio-2015, label

I have loaded a windows form from a .dll and it is displaying correctly and I can execute methods created in that .dll.

[image: Main window with Form1 window opened (from the dll)]

Note the text label in the Form1 window.  In my main window I click debug then select an option that should change the text label to another string.  However the string refuses to change. I have checked that the method in Form1 is firing, and that the label.text has been changed yet the display never changes.

NOTE: This also happens with other controls I have tested (textbox/listbox etc).

```
public void Command(string cmd, string param1, string param2, string param3)
        {
            if (cmd == "TEST")
            {
                this.label1.Text = "This should now change";
                MessageBox.Show("DONE");
            }
        }
```

The MessageBox shows as expected, the label.text has changed, and all events fire correctly (I created a click event for the label which works), it just seems that the label is not actually updating. I have tried using Refresh on the label also.

One other question if possible, :)  Is there a particular way that I can create a callback on the main form that I can supply to Form1? Some kind of delegate I presume?

I load from the dll this way

```
    try
    {
        Type interfaceType = typeof(IPlugin);
        // Fetch all the types that implement the interface IPlugin and are a class
        Type[] types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
            .Where(p => interfaceType.IsAssignableFrom(p) && p.IsClass)
            .ToArray();
        foreach (Type type in types)
        {
            // Create a new instance of all found types
            PluginLists.All.Add((IPlugin)Activator.CreateInstance(type));
            Console.WriteLine("Plugin loaded: {0}", type.ToString());
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Plugins loaded: {0}", PluginLists.All.Count);
    }
```

And, each dll implements a method which starts up the form

```
public void Plugin_Start(DockPanel _dockPanel)
{
    //
    var miscForm = new frmMiscellaneousTest();
    miscForm.Show(_dockPanel, DockState.DockRight);
}
```

Thank you for any help given, it is much appreciated.

Comment: call Invalidate mathod

Comment: @vivek: I have tried that, apologies for not mentioning it in my OP.  It does not change, :(

Comment: Have you tried to refresh the control or the entire form after changing the value. Form1.Refresh()   or Label1.Refresh()

Comment: Yes, I have tried all that.  It is probably something simple that I am missing, :/

The code that I have in a method in Form1 is now:
`

            if (cmd == "TEST")
            {
                label1.Text = "This should now change";
                bool test = label1.InvokeRequired;
                label1.Invalidate(true);
                label1.Update();
                label1.Refresh();
                this.Invalidate(true);
                this.Update();
                this.Refresh();
            }
`
Nothing seems to be happening, :(

Comment: Do you use simple Winforms or some Framework? I know DevExpress Controls always got Properties like AllowEdit or sth. If this is false text won't change.

Comment: It is simple winforms.  All I have done is load and instantiate a windows form from a dll.  Events for that form work correctly, and checking the value of the label in the debugger shows that it is changed. It is just the displaying that doesn't.

Comment: UPDATE: I created a button on Form1 to change the text and clicking that button works correctly.  It just seems that when calling into Form1 from my main form will update values but the UI does not change at all..

Answer (score 0):

I was using the below code (commented out now) to show the form, but I had totally forgotten that I was already in the form and did not need to instantiate it again, :(

```
public void Plugin_Start()
{
    //
    this.Show();
    //var MiscForm = new frmMiscellaneousTest();
    //MiscForm.Show();
}
```